# Cycle in dependencies between targets 'FirebaseStorage' and 'FirebaseCore'; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwMC5.png):
`Cycle in dependencies between targets 'FirebaseStorage' and 'FirebaseCore'; building could produce unreliable results.`

Tried Updating all the packages to their latest versions but it didnt help.

[These are the packages I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtvIM.png)

I used Swift Package Manager to install the dependencies.

Comment: Did you try `In Xcode: Product -> Clean Build Folder`?

Comment: @ArturA Thank you, I don't know why I didn't try that. I did as you said, and it's working as expected now. Thank you.